# render a jinja2 template object in pylons with filters

Tags: python, pylons, jinja2

I'm working on a pylons project that uses jinja2 as its template engine. The project has lots of custom filters added into the template engine.

I have a template object:

```
>>> t = Template("this is a template {{ var|custom_filter }}!!")
>>> t.render(var="woop woop")
```

In this example i get `TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'custom_filter'` How can I easily render template objects without having to either: load them from files, or manually adding each custom filter each time I want to render a template.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the filters into the application environment. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368597/how-do-i-create-a-jinja2-filter-and-use-it-within-pylons) for Pylons-specific instructions on how to do so:

```
from yourapp.lib import extensions

config['pylons.app_globals'].jinja2_env = Environment(loader=ChoiceLoader(
            [FileSystemLoader(path) for path in paths['templates']]),
             extensions=[extensions.custom_filter, ...]))
```

Comment: That only works for adding filters to the template system when you load templates from the filesystem. I'm loading templates from strings.